# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis on Accounts Table and I don't know why

Tags: database, oracle

```
-- Table: Users
CREATE TABLE Users 
(
    User_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Username VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    Registration_Date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
    LastLogin_Date DATE NOT NULL
);


-- Table: Profile
CREATE TABLE Profiles 
(
    Profile_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    User_ID NUMBER(10) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    DateOfBirth DATE NOT NULL,
    Gender VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Address VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    PhoneNumber VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES Users(User_ID)
);

-- Table: Accounts
CREATE TABLE Accounts 
(
    Account_Number VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    User_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
    Account_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Balance NUMBER(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES Users(User_ID)
);

-- Table: Transaction
CREATE TABLE Transactions 
(
    Transaction_ID NUMBER(10) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    Account_Number VARCHAR(13)  NOT NULL,
    Amount NUMBER(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    Transaction_Type VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (Account_Number) REFERENCES Accounts(Account_Number)
);
```

I tried to look for errors on other tables but I couldn't find any

Comment: You've tagged this with MySQL but you reported an Oracle error code. Tag only the database you're actually using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Syntax says that `DEFAULT` goes first, `NOT NULL` next; that's in `accounts` table:

```
SQL> -- Table: Accounts
SQL> CREATE TABLE Accounts
  2  (
  3      Account_Number VARCHAR(13) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  4      User_ID NUMBER(10) NOT NULL,
  5      Account_Name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  6      Balance NUMBER(10) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ,            --> here
  7      FOREIGN KEY (User_ID) REFERENCES Users(User_ID)
  8  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

That's what you did in `users` table:

```
Registration_Date DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL,
```

so you should have just applied the same in other table(s).

---

Apart from that, Oracle recommends we use `varchar2` instead of `varchar` datatype.

Comment: thank you soooo muuchhh, I didn't notice that one due to fatigue

Comment: You're welcome; don't worry, it happens to (mostly) everyone now and then.